# What is the terminology to qualify things that are not reduced when shared (ideas vs physical objects)?

Tags: terminology, idea, property

Is there a defined terminology to refer to things:

- Which gets "reduced" when shared: for example if I have 2 apples and I give you one, now I have one apple
- Which stays the same when shared: for example if I have an idea and I share it with you, I still have the idea intact

I'm looking for two adjectives that would allow to describe this difference of fundamental nature of things (like intensive/extensive properties in physics).

Comment: [Concrete and abstract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_and_concrete).

Comment: In econ there're clear definitions of [private and public goods](https://theinvestorsbook.com/public-goods-vs-private-goods.html) for your spec. As for contemporary analytic philosophy since Wittgenstein it could be even rightly questionable any *private* thing really exists objectively as already reflected by the ancient famous [anattā doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatt%C4%81) which rejects and thus renounces the former...

Comment: In economics the proper term is "[non-rival](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivalry_(economics))". If I take an apple, you have to take another one. But if I take the road, you can still take it. Infrastructures, broadcast, electronic files are all considered non-rival goods.